# How to Invalidate session once page refresh in angular4

Tags: angular

I want to invalidate session and redirect to login page once click on browser refresh button. I have tried using the @HostListener and the page is redirecting to login but again coming to the same page.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) unloadHandler(event: Event) {
    // console.log("Processing beforeunload...");
    // event.returnValue = false;
     this.router.navigate(['/']);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you might have some logic on `login` component for redirection like if already logged in navigate to dashboard. You will have to reset the value for (`already logged in`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vishnu try this...

clear the **`browser storage's`** which your using for **`Authentication`** and if you used any Global variables for binding inside your application, then redirect to login page.

```
localStorage.clear();
sessionStorage.clear();
this.router.navigate(['/login'])
```

I hope this will work...

Comment: I am able to redirect to login page after clearing the session. Thanks for your valuable advice.

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing a page in angular means that your whole angular app will be restarted. As your app is restarting and you want to invalidate session, so clear all session or localvariables on the starting of your app itself, better place will be to do it in ngOnInit of app.component.ts.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to keep a isrefresh variable to load the page

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard', { isrefresh:false }]);
```

In dashboard's load event, check if isrefresh is true. If true, redirect to login page.

```
this.route.paramMap.pipe( switchMap((params: ParamMap) => { 
this.isrefresh = params.get('isrefresh'); 
})
);



If (isrefresh){
//Redirect to login page
}
```